# Denoising Autoencoder returns a mostly black image

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, autoencoder

I have some faces cropped out of images, and I want to run them through a denoising autoencoder, the code which I got from [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html). When I run the code on the MNIST dataset, the results look fine, like the ones in the website. However, when I run it on my own images, I get a mostly or completely black image in return instead of simply the same image without the noise.

This is the [original image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1jKU.png) before I resized it, so you can tell how it looks.

This is the [image after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isfcY.png) which I had to do in order to feed it to the autoencoder. I sized it down to be 28x28.

These are the [results plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icfQu.png). For the first results, I actually expect my original grayscale image to appear before I've fed it into the autoencoder. For the second row, I had wanted it to be the same image but without the noise. As you can see, I get these odd outputs and I can't tell why.

Here is the code I've tried on the MNIST dataset. For my dataset, I skipped the preprocessing of the MNIST dataset and instead preprocessed my own images (Sized them down, made them grayscale...Their dimensions are (28, 28, 1), just like the original code intended. I tried changing the number of Epochs (I went through 10, 50, and 100), but there was no noticeable difference. I considered changing the layers, but after looking at some papers and other code, the layers seem to be the same as the ones presented. I tried looking up tutorials where the autoencoder works on regular images like mine and not just the MNIST dataset, but I couldn't really find any. I'm also confused as to why, when I plot the original array, I get black squares, even though when I use cv2_imshow to relay it I get the image I showed after resizing. I don't really know if it's the same issue. I've also tried training the autoencoder on my own dataset (Which has 785 images similar to the ones I've shown above), but to no avail. I've displayed the code I used down, and if there is something missing needed to understand my question please tell me.

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

noise_factor = 0.5
x_train_noisy = x_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_train.shape) 
x_test_noisy = x_test + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_test.shape) 

x_train_noisy = np.clip(x_train_noisy, 0., 1.)
x_test_noisy = np.clip(x_test_noisy, 0., 1.)

n = 10
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 2))
for i in range(1, n):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, n, i)
    plt.imshow(x_test_noisy[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()

input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (7, 7, 32)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(grayscale, grayscale,
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(grayscale, grayscale),
                callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/tb', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True)])
```

Here is the code I used to feed my image into the autoencoder and display the results.

```
arr= cv2.imread('/content/FramesResized/frame0000sec.jpg')

#Converting the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Adding an axis as when the image was converted to grayscale, it become (28,28) and I need it to be (28,28,1)
if gray.ndim == 2:
    gray = np.expand_dims(gray, axis=2)

#Making a new array to take my images, currently of which there is only one
grayscale = np.zeros([785, 28, 28, 1], dtype=np.uint8)
grayscale[0] = gray

#Feeding my image into the autoencoder
decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(grayscale)

#Plotting the before and after images
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(1, n):
    # display original
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i)
    plt.imshow(grayscale[i].reshape(28,28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + n)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, I believe the issue was that I was applying an autoencoder that was trained on MNIST images to complex, RGB images, so the autoencoder reconstruction was very poor.

When I used the CIFAR-100 dataset to train the autoencoder, the results were much more coherent.